# find the amount of elementary matrix required for a 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

can someone help me with this question?

question:

Given a 2 × 2 invertible matrix, we have seen we can write it as a product of elementary matrices. What is the largest amount of elementary matrices required? Give an example of a matrix that requires this number of elementary matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by an elementary matrix?

Comment: it is a matrix obtained by performing operations on the identity matrix

Comment: Which operations? Change in rows, multiplication of a row by a constant, and sum of two rows?

Comment: yes, those operations

Comment: I recently answered this question for another user.  You can find the discussion here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985411